# convert case of wide characters, given the LCID (Visual C++)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, uppercase, lowercase, lcid

I have some existing Visual C++ code where I need to add the conversion of wide character strings to upper or lower case.

I know there are pitfalls to this (such as the Turkish "I"), but most of these can be ironed-out if you know the language. Fortunately in this area of code I know the LCID value (locale ID) which I guess is the same as knowing the language.

As LCID is a Windows type, is there a Windows function that will convert wide strings to upper or lower case?

The C runtime function _towupper_l() sounds like it would be ideal but it takes a _locale_t parameter instead of LCID, so I guess it's unsuitable unless there is a completely reliable way of converting an LCID to a _locale_t.

Comment: Can't you use `towupper` or `towlower`?

Comment: No. Sorry I forgot to add a comment about that in my original post. The doc for towupper() says "The case conversion of towupper is locale-specific. Only the characters relevant to the current locale are changed in case. The functions without the _l suffix use the currently set locale. The versions of these functions with the _l suffix take the locale as a parameter and use that instead of the currently set locale". The LCID may not be the current locale, so you need to use the _l version and pass-in the applicable _locale_t to get a reliable result using that locale.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're searching for is called [`LCMapString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318700.aspx) and it is part of the Windows NLS APIs. The `LCMAP_UPPERCASE` flag maps characters to uppercase, while the `LCMAP_LOWERCASE` maps characters to lowercase.

For applications targeting Windows Vista and later, there is [an `Ex` variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318702.aspx) that works on locale names instead of identifiers, which are what Microsoft now says you should prefer to use.

In fact, in the CRT implementation provided with VS 2010 (and presumably other versions as well), functions such as `_towupper_l` ultimately end up calling `LCMapString` after they extract the locale ID (LCID) from the specified `_locale_t`.

If you're like me, and less familiar with the i8n APIs than you should be, you probably already know about the [`CharUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647474.aspx), [`CharLower`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647467.aspx), [`CharUpperBuff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647475.aspx), and [`CharLowerBuff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647468.aspx) family of functions. These have been the old standbys from the early days of Windows for altering the case of chars/strings, but as their documentation warns:

> Note that `CharXxx` always maps uppercase I to lowercase I ("i"), even when the current language is Turkish or Azeri. If you need a function that is linguistically sensitive in this respect, call [`LCMapString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318700.aspx).

What it neglects to mention is filled in by a couple of posts on Michael Kaplan's wonderful blog on internationalization issues: [What does "linguistic casing" mean?](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/11/279942.aspx), [How best to alter case](http://www.siao2.com/2005/10/18/482088.aspx). The executive summary is that you achieve the same results as the `CharXxx` family of functions by calling `LCMapString` and *not* specifying the `LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING` flag, whereas you can be linguistically sensitive by ensuring that you *do* specify the `LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING` flag.

Sample code:

```
std::wstring test("Does my code pass the Turkey test?");
if (!LCMapStringW(lcid,            /* your LCID, defined elsewhere */
                  LCMAP_UPPERCASE | LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING,
                  test.c_str(),    /* input string */
                  test.length(),   /* length of input string */
                  &test[0],        /* output buffer (can reuse input) */
                  test.length()))  /* length of output buffer (same as input) */
{
   // Uh-oh! Something went wrong in the call to LCMapString, so you need to
   // handle the error somehow here.
   // A good start is calling GetLastError to determine the error code.
}
```